# Changing ellipse color in a Goocanvas

Tags: c++, gtkmm

I'm trying to change the color of a state (represented by an ellipse) to illustrate when it's active, but I get this error:

Segmentation fault (core dumped)

The code is:

```
    int AutomataGui::setNodeAsActive(std::string nodeName){
    GuiNode* node = this->getNodeByName(nodeName);
    if (node == NULL)
        return -1;
    this->drawAsActiveNode(node);
    return 0;
 }

    GuiNode* AutomataGui::getNodeByName(std::string name){
        std::list<GuiNode> nodeList = *(this->currentGuiSubautomata->getListGuiNodes());

        std::list<GuiNode>::iterator nodeListIter = nodeList.begin();
        while (nodeListIter != nodeList.end()){
            if (nodeListIter->getName().compare(name) == 0){
                return &(*nodeListIter);
            }
            nodeListIter++;
        }
    return NULL;
}

    void AutomataGui::drawAsActiveNode(GuiNode* gnode){
    if (this->currentActiveNode){
        this->currentActiveNode->changeColor(ITEM_COLOR_BLUE);
    }
    gnode->changeColor(ITEM_COLOR_GREEN);
    this->currentActiveNode = gnode;
 }

    void GuiNode::changeColor ( std::string newColor ){
    #ifdef GLIBMM_PROPERTIES_ENABLED
    this->ellipse->property_fill_color() = newColor;
    #else
    this->ellipse->set_property("fill_color", Glib::ustring(newColor));
    #endif //GLIBMM_PROPERTIES_ENABLED
}
```

The thing is that `this->currentActiveNode` is `NULL` it works fine, but when it isn't it gives me the error.

Comment: You have a segfault so it would be best to start by using gdb to get a backtrace. Valgrind might also be helpful.